# Why Do I get the memory adress instead of the real value ? Pointer c++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, dereference

```
int x = 2;
int y=8;
int* p = &x; 
*p=y;

cout << p <<endl;
```

> my question is: why do I get the memory adress when I Print p and not the actual value since I already dereferenced it in line 4

Comment: You have to deference the pointer _every time_ you need the pointed-to value.

Comment: Dereferencing `p` doesn't change what `p` is.   So dereferencing it in line 4 doesn't negate the need to dereference it in subsequent code (assuming you want to access the value pointed to by `p`, rather than the value of `p` itself).

Answer (score 3):

```
cout << *p << endl;
```

is what you need.
When you try to output something to stdout, compiler automatically infer its type and call the corresponding function. In your case, p is pointer type, therefore the address is printed, and since *p is int type, you should use *p if you want to print the value.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a misconception about dereferencing pointers.

> ...since I already dereferenced it in line 4

Dereferencing means to retrieve the value the pointer is pointing to. It doesn't change the pointer itself in any way. `p` is still a pointer after `*p=y;`.

All `*p=y` does, is to change the value `p` is pointing to, it doesn't change the pointer itself.